# how to install third party lib without composer in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, autoloader, lib

I am new in yii2. I have a php class and I want to use it in yii2 but I don't know how to add in autoloader.

I use it now as follow:

```
require_once '/vendor/xplore-php-sdk/xplore-php-sdk.php';

$query = new XPLORE('h3zjkzrgvt6fyx2huwn65hy9');
$query->doi($doi);
$result = $query->callAPI();
```

how can I add it in yii2?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not giving this class proper app namespace and putting it in correct path, so it will be autoloaded like all other classes in project?

Comment: @rob006 yes. it will be autoloaded

Comment: You can place the file at components / lib instead of vendor, use namespace to include autoload it